# Linux - Shell does not redirect outputs

Tags: c++, linux, shell, fork, exec

I created a simple shell in Linux using `fork()` and `execvp()`. It works fine with cat, ls etc. but when I try to redirect its output like `./hello.o > output.txt` it doesn't work.

I am guessing I didn't provide the write path to look for the definitions. My shell is currently searching on `/bin/` path where most of the commands are stored.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ARG_SIZE 100    // MAX LENGTH FOR ARGUMENTS
#define PATH "/bin/"    // PATH FOR ARGUMENTS

int main() {
    char inputLine[BUFSIZ];
    char *argv[ARG_SIZE];

    // for path + argv
    char programPath[200];

    while (1) {
        printf("myshell> ");    

        // check if ctrl + D is pressed 
        if (fgets(inputLine, BUFSIZ, stdin) == NULL) 
            break;

        inputLine[strlen(inputLine) - 1] = '\0';

        // check if exit is typed
        if (strcmp(inputLine, "exit") == 0)
            break;

        int i = 0;

        argv[0] = strtok(inputLine, " \n");
        for (i = 0; argv[i] && i < ARG_SIZE-1; ++i)
            argv[++i] = strtok(NULL, " \n");

        // create a fork call
        pid_t pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        // parent
        if (pid != 0) {
            wait();

        // child
        } else {
            strcat(programPath, argv[0]);

            // will not return unless it fails
            execvp(programPath, argv); 

            perror("execvp");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "to execute files like `./hello.o`" Sorry, like... what? Like an object file? Have you tried executing it directly from the shell?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I can excute `./hello` straight from terminal but when I try to run it from my shell CLI, it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Also, you can type `echo $PATH` and see your path. You don't need to guess.

Comment: `hello.o` is typically not an executable but an intermediate *binary* that needs to be *linked* before it can run.

Comment: Are you trying to run `./hello.o` or `./hello` because sometimes you are saying one and other times you are saying the other.

Comment: @Galik okay, my bad `./hello` was working, there was a space before I typed in the command, that was the problem. But I can't redirect its output. Example: hello.c just prints hello world, I need to redirect it to a text file like `./hello > output.txt` but this just prints hello world on the screen and doesn't create a text file.

Comment: This sounds like a `C` question rather than a `C++` question. `hello.c` is typically a `C` program. `C++` programs usually end in `.cpp`.

Comment: But the source of your new problem is possibly in how you coded `hello.c`.

Comment: @Galik hello.c just has `printf("Hello World");` I don't think this will create a problem in redirecting outputs.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question! If your question is "why doesn't it redirect", the answer is "because it has no redirection code". (There's no code to look for a `<` or a `>` in the command line, open the file, and hook it up to the child process' stdin or stdout.) If the question is something else, what is it?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Let me rephrase my question then. How do I look for `>` in my program so that it redirect its output?

Comment: @hassanyf You use `char *rightArrow = strchr(inputLine, '>')`. You need to do all the stuff -- parse the line, open the file, hook it up. If you get into trouble with some specific part of that code, *then* ask a question about what you're stuck on. But you haven't done anything yet.